# Initializing tkinter gui leads to main thread not in main loop

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

My question is regarding initializing a GUI built with tkinter. I'm starting another thread within the GUI that's running a script which takes 10 minutes to finish. The reason I'm doing this in another thread is to be able to keep the GUI responsive during these 10 minutes.

Right now I'm trying to do the following (simplified)

```
   import tkinter as tk
   from threading import Thread
   class GUI:
        def __init__(self):
            self.master = tk.Tk()
            self.master.geometry("1400x700")
            // 
            ...
            //
            self.master.mainloop()
        
        def run_long_script(self): # Called by button in GUI
            self.t1 = Thread(target = long_script)
            self.start()

        def long_script(self):
            try:
                ...
            except InterruptedError as error:
    GUI()
```

This works okay, but when I try to close the GUI with `long_script` running, I get the error message `main thread not in main loop`. How should I design the code to be able to close the program correctly?

Comment: GUI has to run only in main thread. In other thread you can make some calculations but results you have to send to main thread and main thread has to update widgets. So all depends on what you have in `long_script`.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I have a for loop in the long_script, that updates a progress bar in the main window everytime it ends an iteration. Might that be why i get the error message?

Comment: progress bar has to be updated in main thread. Other thread may set global variable and main thread may use `root.after(milliseconds, function)` to run periodically function which will get value from global variable and update progressbar.

Comment: I have only example which runs code in `multiprocess` and it uses `queue` to send value to main process and this process uses `after()` to periodically check `queue` and update `progressbar` - [furas/python-examples/tkinter/progressbar](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/progressbar/progressbar-multiprocessing-process-queue/main.py)

Answer (score 1):

`Tkinter` like many other GUIs can use widgets only in main thread
(or rather in thread which runs `mainlooop`).

Other thread has to update global value (which is shared between threads) or use `queue` to send value to main thread. And main thread has to use `after(milliseconds, function_name)` to run periodically function which will get value from global variable or from `queue` and update progress bar.

---

Minimal working code.

```
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

# --- functions ---

def long_script():
    global progress_value
    
    for i in range(20):
        print('loop:', i)
        
        # update global variable
        progress_value += 5
        
        time.sleep(.5)

def run_long_script():
    global progress_value
    global t
    
    if t is None: # run only one thread
        # set start value
        progress_value = 0
        # start updating progressbar
        update_progressbar()
        # start thread
        t = threading.Thread(target=long_script)
        t.start()
    else:
        print('Already running')
        
def update_progressbar():
    global t
    
    # update progressbar
    pb['value'] = progress_value
    
    if progress_value < 100:
        # run it again after 100ms
        root.after(100, update_progressbar)
    else:
        # set None so it can run thread again
        t = None
        
# --- main ---

# default value at start
progress_value = 0  
t = None

# - gui -

root = tk.Tk()

pb = ttk.Progressbar(root, mode="determinate")
pb.pack()

b = tk.Button(root, text="start", command=run_long_script)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Doesn't this update_progressbar-function get recursive and take up a lot of computer power?

Comment: it is not recurison - after add it to special list which mainloop check in every loop and function is executed by mainloop. I think there is no other method - and if there are other methods then they work in similar way - they check something periodically - but you don't see it. Besides it doesn't use so many CPU power.

Comment: Perfect, I decided to use a monitor object to keep track of the progrssbar combined with your method, which worked out fine!